# Can I Shift tokens in a FOR /f loop?

Tags: batch-file

is there a way to Shift through tokens in a For /f loop.
For example:

```
set VAR=10
set Counter=1
:LOOP
If Not "%Counter%=="%VAR%" (
FOR /f "Tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 delims=;" %%A in (FILE.csv) DO (
 set %%A=RESULT_[!Counter!]
 SHIFT
 set /a Counter=%Counter%+1
 GOTO LOOP
)
GOTO EOF
```

I hope you can see what I try to do. I want to safe every token in a separate variable.

Is that possible?

EDIT
file.csv example:

```
test.bat;test.sh;example.bat;example2.bat;etc...
```

I just want to save each .bat or .sh file in different variables.

Comment: Please edit in a sample of your `file.csv` and show what  you *expect* the code to achieve given some sample input as command-line arguments. You appear to be totally on the wrong track...

Comment: no. But you can pass the tokens to a subroutine where you can.